# Find the inverse of the following linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the inverse of the linear map

$φ:ℝ_3[t]\toℝ_3[u], at^2+bt+c\mapsto (a+c)u^2+(b+c)u+(a+b)$

I know I need to take an arbitrary element in $ℝ_3[u]$ and solve $φ(at^2+bt+c)=xu^2+yu+z$.

But now I am completely blank and have no clue what to do, or how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try writing down a matrix representation of the map and then inverting the matrix.

Comment: How would you do that? They're polynomials.

Comment: The last equation should be "$\varphi( ...$" not "$\varphi_2( ...$". And what is $\varphi(at^2 + bt + c)$? According to the definition the equation becomes $(a + c)u^2 + (b + c)u + (a + b) = xu^2 + yu + z$. Now you should be able to solve for $x, y, z$. Alternatively, you can use matrices as suggested by mtiano which are useful when the system of equations you obtain are more complicated.

Comment: Sorry, $φ_2$ was a typo.

Comment: @MrCroutini In order to solve it using matrices, you first need a basis. For example $\beta = \{1, t, t^2\}$ and $\gamma = \{1, u, u^2\}$. Then you can get a vector representation of the polynomial $at^2 + bt + c$ as $(c, b, a)^T$. You can also get the matrix representation of $\varphi$ and you last equation becomes a matrix equation.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar, how do I solve for x,y,z?

Comment: @MrCroutini You have the equation $(a + c)u^2 + (b + c)u + (a + b) = xu^2 + yu + z$. Two polynomials are equal only when their coefficients are equal. So you have the system of equations $a + c = x, b + c = y, a + b = z$. Now solve this system for $a, b, c$ (sorry, I should have said solve for $a, b, c$ before). For example eq1 + eq3 - eq2 gives $(a + c) + (a + b) - (b + c) = x + z - y \implies a = \frac{1}{2}(x + z - y)$.

Once you solve for $a,b,c$, you can write down the formula for the inverse as $\varphi^{-1}(xu^2 + yu + z) = at^2 + bt + c$ you know the coefficients in terms of $x, y, z$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I understand now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, we can use $\beta=\{1,t,t^2\}$ and $\gamma=\{1,u,u^2\}$ as bases for the vector spaces, and then the matrix of $\phi$ with respect to these bases is given by

$\begin{bmatrix}[\phi(1)]_{\gamma}&[\phi(t)]_{\gamma}&[\phi(t^2)]_{\gamma}\end{bmatrix}$ where $\phi(1)=u^2+u$, $\phi(t)=u+1$, and $\phi(t^2)=u^2+1$.

Therefore the matrix is given by $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\1&1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and then $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&1\\1&1&-1\\1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ will be the matrix representing the inverse of
$\phi$ with respect to these bases.